# User cannot view their Orders in Ubercart

Tags: ubercart

For Drupal (v7.22) I have a basic install of Ubercart (v7.x-3.4) and have set the permissions to allow an authenticated user to 'View own orders' and View own invoices'. But if an authenticated user visits an order page (for an order they made) they get the error:

page: example.com/user/user_name/orders/1

> Access denied
>
> You are not authorized to access this page.

I've been though all of the settings and googled this but cannot see what I've missed. Does anyone know if I've missed a permission/setting somewhere?

Comment: Please use http://example.com and http://example.org in examples, not commercial domains.

Comment: this is not an error, its an permission issue

Comment: @Bala with "View own orders" set to true, how "access denied" is not an error? I mean, it's not an error in the module, it works for way to many people, but it is something wrong with OP's setup, and if you have a clue what it might be, please share.

Comment: @Mołot it encourage me to post answer

Answer (score 1):

Enable the **Allow customers to view order invoices from their order history** in Order settings, see the below image may be this will be the problem for you and i am not sure because i have drupal 6 installation only.

[image]